# Sybase SQL Append to Variable in SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am running Sybase SQL 12.5.1.

I am trying to combine the values of rows into a delimited list.

I'm expecting the following statement to return "1;2;3", but it returns ;3.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp3(x varchar(5))
INSERT INTO #temp3 values('1')
INSERT INTO #temp3 values('2')
INSERT INTO #temp3 values('3')
SELECT * FROM #temp3


DECLARE @CombinedValues varchar(8000)
SELECT @CombinedValues = COALESCE(@CombinedValues, ';', '') + #temp3.x FROM #temp3
SELECT @CombinedValues
DROP TABLE #temp3
```

It looks like @CombinedValues is only getting the last value, but it should have all of them.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you're talking about ASE, not SQL Anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #temp3(x varchar(5))
INSERT INTO #temp3 values('1')
INSERT INTO #temp3 values('2')
INSERT INTO #temp3 values('3')

DECLARE @CombinedValues varchar(8000)=''
SELECT @CombinedValues += x+';' FROM #temp3
PRINT @CombinedValues
DROP TABLE #temp3
```

Comment: If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: It won't let me to +=, I don't thinks that's valid in this sql version.

Comment: Then use SELECT CombinedValues = CombinedValues +

Answer (score 1):

If previous answer does not work (does not work for me) then please try below:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #temp3 (
    x   varchar(5)
)
INSERT INTO #temp3 values('1')
INSERT INTO #temp3 values('2')
INSERT INTO #temp3 values('3')

DECLARE @CombinedValues varchar(8000)

update  #temp3
set     @CombinedValues = @CombinedValues + x + ';'
FROM    #temp3

PRINT @CombinedValues

DROP TABLE #temp3
```

Cheers